# How can I parse a C header file with Perl?

Tags: python, c, perl, parsing, header-files

I have a header file in which there is a large struct. I need to read this structure using some program and make some operations on each member of the structure and write them back.

For example I have some structure like

```
const BYTE Some_Idx[] = {
4,7,10,15,17,19,24,29,
31,32,35,45,49,51,52,54,
55,58,60,64,65,66,67,69,
70,72,76,77,81,82,83,85,
88,93,94,95,97,99,102,103,
105,106,113,115,122,124,125,126,
129,131,137,139,140,149,151,152,
153,155,158,159,160,163,165,169,
174,175,181,182,183,189,190,193,
197,201,204,206,208,210,211,212,
213,214,215,217,218,219,220,223,
225,228,230,234,236,237,240,241,
242,247,249};
```

Now, I need to read this and apply some operation on each of the member variable and create a new structure with different order, something like:

```
const BYTE Some_Idx_Mod_mul_2[] = {
8,14,20, ...
...
484,494,498};
```

Is there any Perl library already available for this? If not Perl, something else like Python is also OK.

Can somebody please help!!!

Comment: Any particular reason to not use C? I would think that is a logical way to address this problem.

Comment: are you just reading and modifying a C header? Why?

Comment: @Ryan, Can you be a bit more elaborate. Are you saying that I can use the same header file from inside C, and then use it for parsing?

@Carson, Actually, I just gave an example, I need to do things like splitting, merging and things like that.

Comment: right, but, what is the purpose of this data... Like, are you saving work for yourself by automating declarations in a header or something? Why are you parsing the header instead of dynamically creating these arrays?

Comment: @Carson, the header file data will be eventually made into ROM data for the Hardware. This needs some specific format, that suits the ROM table generation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keeping your data lying around in a header makes it trickier to get at using other programs like Perl. Another approach you might consider is to keep this data in a database or another file and regenerate your header file as-needed, maybe even as part of your build system. The reason for this is that generating C is much easier than parsing C, it's trivial to write a script that parses a text file and makes a header for you, and such a script could even be invoked from your build system.

Assuming that you want to keep your data in a C header file, you will need one of two things to solve this problem:

- a quick one-off script to parse exactly (or close to exactly) the input you describe.
- a general, well-written script that can parse arbitrary C and work generally on to lots of different headers.

The first case seems more common than the second to me, but it's hard to tell from your question if this is better solved by a script that needs to parse arbitrary C or a script that needs to parse this specific file. For code that works on your specific case, the following works for me on your input:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

open FILE, "<header.h" or die $!;
my @file = <FILE>;
close FILE or die $!;

my $in_block = 0;
my $regex = 'Some_Idx\[\]';
my $byte_line = '';
my @byte_entries;
foreach my $line (@file) {
    chomp $line;

    if ( $line =~ /$regex.*\{(.*)/ ) {
        $in_block = 1;
        my @digits = @{ match_digits($1) };
        push @digits, @byte_entries;
        next;
    }

    if ( $in_block ) {
        my @digits = @{ match_digits($line) };
        push @byte_entries, @digits;
    }

    if ( $line =~ /\}/ ) {
        $in_block = 0;
    }
}

print "const BYTE Some_Idx_Mod_mul_2[] = {\n";
print join ",", map { $_ * 2 } @byte_entries;
print "};\n";

sub match_digits {
    my $text = shift;
    my @digits;
    while ( $text =~ /(\d+),*/g ) {
        push @digits, $1;
    }

    return \@digits;
}
```

Parsing arbitrary C is a little tricky and not worth it for many applications, but maybe you need to actually do this. One trick is to let GCC do the parsing for you and read in GCC's parse tree using a CPAN module named [GCC::TranslationUnit](http://search.cpan.org/~awin/GCC-TranslationUnit-1.00/TranslationUnit.pm). 
Here's the GCC command to compile the code, assuming you have a single file named test.c:

gcc -fdump-translation-unit -c test.c

Here's the Perl code to read in the parse tree:

```
  use GCC::TranslationUnit;

  # echo '#include <stdio.h>' > stdio.c
  # gcc -fdump-translation-unit -c stdio.c
  $node = GCC::TranslationUnit::Parser->parsefile('stdio.c.tu')->root;

  # list every function/variable name
  while($node) {
    if($node->isa('GCC::Node::function_decl') or
       $node->isa('GCC::Node::var_decl')) {
      printf "%s declared in %s\n",
        $node->name->identifier, $node->source;
    }
  } continue {
    $node = $node->chain;
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but why worry about parsing the file at all? Why not write a C program that #includes the header, processes it as required and then spits out the source for the modified header. I'm sure this would be simpler than the Perl/Python solutions, and it would be much more reliable because the header would be being parsed by the C compilers parser.

Comment: @Neil, the header file data will be eventually made into ROM data for the Hardware. This needs some specific format, that suits the ROM table generation. And there are a lot of header-files with different variable names, and I am not sure if they can included at run-time.

Comment: I don't mean include the header in your real program, I mean write ANOTHER program to process the header, but write that program in C not Perl or Python.

Comment: @Neil, I think your idea will be good if we have a few h(eader) files. But what we have here is around 100+ header files, each with an average of around 10 different datastructure definition. We thought, including all these in a C file will be a big task. The parsing formula we are planning to apply is the same for all the files, so we thought parsing (may) be a nice idea. But then, we will implement it using C if no other method works out.

Comment: You can also write a program that writes the C program.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really provide much information about how what is to be modified should be determined, but to address your specific example:

```
$ perl -pi.bak -we'if ( /const BYTE Some_Idx/ .. /;/ ) { s/Some_Idx/Some_Idx_Mod_mul_2/g; s/(\d+)/$1 * 2/ge; }' header.h
```

Breaking that down, -p says loop through input files, putting each line in `$_`, running the supplied code, then printing `$_`.  -i.bak enables in-place editing, renaming each original file with a .bak suffix and printing to a new file named whatever the original was.  -w enables warnings.  -e'....' supplies the code to be run for each input line.  header.h is the only input file.

In the perl code, `if ( /const BYTE Some_Idx/ .. /;/ )` checks that we are in a range of lines beginning with a line matching `/const BYTE Some_Idx/` and ending with a line matching `/;/`.
s/.../.../g does a substitution as many times as possible.  `/(\d+)/` matches a series of digits.  The /e flag says the result (`$1 * 2`) is code that should be evaluated to produce a replacement string, instead of simply a replacement string.  $1 is the digits that should be replaced.

Answer (score 3):

If all you need to do is to modify structs, you can directly use regex to split and apply changes to each value in the struct, looking for the declaration and the ending }; to know when to stop.

If you really need a more general solution you could use a parser generator, like [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a Perl module called [Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-RecDescent) which is a very powerful recursive descent parser generator. It comes with a bunch of examples. One of them is a [grammar that can parse C](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DCONWAY/Parse-RecDescent-1.96.0/demo/demo_Cgrammar_v2.pl).

Now, I don't think this matters in your case, but the recursive descent parsers using Parse::RecDescent are algorithmically slower (O(n^2), I think) than tools like [Parse::Yapp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-Yapp) or [Parse::EYapp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-EYapp). I haven't checked whether Parse::EYapp comes with such a C-parser example, but if so, that's the tool I'd recommend learning.

Answer (score 2):

Python solution (not full, just a hint ;)) Sorry if any mistakes - not tested

```
import re
text = open('your file.c').read()
patt = r'(?is)(.*?{)(.*?)(}\s*;)'
m = re.search(patt, text)
g1, g2, g3 = m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)
g2 = [int(i) * 2 for i in g2.split(',')
out = open('your file 2.c', 'w')
out.write(g1, ','.join(g2), g3)
out.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a really useful Perl module called [Convert::Binary::C](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Convert-Binary-C/lib/Convert/Binary/C.pm) that parses C header files and converts structs from/to Perl data structures.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) / [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html), to read, and write the data.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @data;
{
  open( my $file, '<', 'Some_Idx.bin' );

  local $/ = \1; # read one byte at a time

  while( my $byte = <$file> ){
    push @data, unpack('C',$byte);
  }
  close( $file );
}

print join(',', @data), "\n";

{
  open( my $file, '>', 'Some_Idx_Mod_mul_2.bin' );

  # You have two options
  for my $byte( @data ){
    print $file pack 'C', $byte * 2;
  }
  # or
  print $file pack 'C*', map { $_ * 2 } @data;

  close( $file );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the GCC::TranslationUnit example see hparse.pl from http://gist.github.com/395160
which will make it into C::DynaLib, and the not yet written Ctypes also.
This parses functions for FFI's, and not bare structs contrary to Convert::Binary::C. 
hparse will only add structs if used as func args.